# Changing the value of a constant in a class

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

Working through Apple's Swift Programming Guide I came across this example in the explanation of ARC;

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        println("\(name) is being initialized")
    }
    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

var reference1: Person?
var reference2: Person?
var reference3: Person?
```

I understand the idea that because the variables are of the option type they are initialized with a value of nil and do not reference a Person instance.  So the following makes sense to me;

```
reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
```

However I was experimenting and was surprised to see I could also do this;

```
reference1 = Person(name: "Johnny Appleseed")
```

I was expecting the code to error since I was trying to change the constant "name" property.  Not only can I change this property I also got the message "Johnny Appleseed is being initialized".  How can I be initializing a constant twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not actually *changing* the `name` property of your existing `Person` instance.

What you're doing is creating a **new** `Person`, and giving him the name "Johnny". Your old `Person` with the name "John" will be deallocated automatically:

```
reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
reference1 = Person(name: "Johnny Appleseed") // "John" is now gone.
```

Unless you have some other variable pointing to "John", that instance will be deallocated.

This *would* cause a compilation error:

```
reference1 = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
reference1.name = "Johnny Appleseed"
```

Because you'd be trying to change the value of a property defined using `let`.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `Person(name: "Johnny Appleseed")` you creating a new Person object that replaces the old Person object referenced by `reference1`. The constant property `name` of the old Person object is not changed at all, thus no error is issued.